# How to exclude a resource from the war file in Grails 2.0?

Tags: grails, build, resources

I have some test data with some special content (images, videos, etc.) in my Grails 2 application that should not be included when building the war. At development time, these files are stored in `web-app/content/`. So the question is, how do I exclude them when build a war for the production environment?

During my search I came accross [this blog post, covering the topic in an earlier Grails version](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2009/01/21/excluding-files-from-a-war-with-grails-the-right-way/). Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work anymore and the comments didn't help me either.

This is what I have tried for now:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    delete { fileset(dir: "${stagingDir}/content/", includes: '*') }
}
```

Maybe I am just missing something? Or is there even a better way to separate test-data from shipping the application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, I was obviously missing something. Or to be more precise sometimes less information is more. After a bit more of googling for `ant delete fileset` I saw that the `includes` attribute is deprecated. After leaving it out, all files in the `content` directory were removed. Even the directory structure is still present, which is exactly what I wanted.

So my solution for now is:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    delete { fileset dir: "${stagingDir}/content/" }
}
```

EDIT:
As far as I know grails uses ant under the hood, so the [Ant Delete Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) is the thing to look at. So I guess if you want to delete the empty subdirectories too, it would be (not checked though):

```
delete(includeEmptyDirs: true) { fileset dir: "${stagingDir}/content/" }
```

or if u want to delete the `content` folder itself just:

```
delete(dir: "${stagingDir}/content/")
```

Comment: Thanks, dude. Did you find a solution to delete folders too ? Regards

Comment: Have a look at my edit. I never checked if it really works though.

Comment: Confirmed, Roland. I tested it

`delete(includeEmptyDirs: true) { fileset dir: "${stagingDir}/content/" }` 
deletes empty subdirectories successfully. Thank you again, my friend.

Comment: Just to complement, you should use BuildConfig.groovy to declare the ‘grails.war.resources’ closure. Thanks