# How would I prevent a view from being included in WAR using Grails

Tags: grails

I have a GSP I am using for my Jasmine Test Spec. I would like to prevent this from being included in the war in certain environments (say production).

Is there a way to exclude gsp views in a war given an environment?

Comment: Do you want it excluded entirely from the WAR or just when the WAR is run with the production environment?

Comment: From an abstract perspective I want it to just give a 404 in prod. I would suspect the easiest way is to somehow exclude it from being included in the war in that env. I want it accessible in all other environments.

Comment: Here is a pretty good solution to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168179/deleting-plugins-views-gsp-when-building-the-war and also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564720/how-to-exclude-a-resource-from-the-war-file-in-grails-2-0