# Yet another gradle dependency issue (Grails 3)

Tags: grails, gradle

I have a Jasper Reports local plugin that works in stand-alone testing, but once brought into a Grails 3.2.4 app there is a dependency issue.

In the plugin, DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance() is handled by the xercesImpl implementation - org\apache\xerces\jaxp\DocumentBuildFactoryImpl.

When the plugin is called within the Grails app, the DocumentBuilder returned is  oracle\jdbc\xmlparser\oracle\impl\jaxp\JXDocumentBuilderFactory.  This comes from xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar

I have tried countless variations in my attempts to avoid the jdbc version from being used by the plugin.  No luck, my latest was

```
compile ("jasperreportsplugin:JasperReportsPlugin:6.5.1.M1") {
    exclude group: 'oracle'
}
```

What's the real solution?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564720/how-to-exclude-a-resource-from-the-war-file-in-grails-2-0

Comment: This deals with excluding a jar from the war build, which is a different situation.  I have dependencies which pull in two different jars that both provide an implementation of javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.  I need the plugin to use a specific class, which is not the defauilt one provided by the application build.